# What is the meaning of all abbreviations in wheel filename notation on Christoph Gohlke's website?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy

I wanted to install OpenCV for Python3 on my machine following [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/) tutorial, but I'm faced with a problem of numpy **version notation** on **Christoph Gohlke's website**, 
more precisely what does for example

> numpy‑1.14.2+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

notation mean, I don't understand what version I have to download. 
Which one of versions listed [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) do I install based on my system specs?

I've read through the header introduction on Christoph Gohlke's website but didn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> numpy‑1.14.2+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

numpy — well, obviously
1.14.2 — version of NumPy
mkl — compiled with [Intel Math Kernel Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library)
cp36‑cp36m — for CPython version 3.6
win32 — for 32-bit Python on Windows (Windows could be 32- or 64-bit)
win_amd64 — for 64-bit Python on Windows (Windows must be 64-bit)
pp360 — PyPy3 version 6.0.

To see what Python you've installed run

```
python.exe -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported())"
```

The output will be something like

```
[('cp27', 'cp27mu', 'linux_aarch64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'linux_aarch64'), ('py2', 'none', 'linux_aarch64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]
```

Comment: thanks for response, but i still don't understand why there is cp36 repeated and why is there a m at the end

Comment: is it that it is compatible with cp36 and cp36m ?

Comment: They are [Python Tag and ABI Tag](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#details).

Comment: So do I need to install mkl first if I want to manually install numpy? Thank you!

Comment: @VickyDing I think it's compiled-in in wheels. You only need to install MKL if you gonna build numpy+mkl from sources; at least that what I believe.