# What is the difference between the various versions of binary wheels?

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel

These are the many versions of the pycairo binary wheels. What is the difference?

> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.2‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.2‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.2‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.2‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
>
> pycairo‑1.18.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

Comment: What do the names suggest? `pycairo‑<lib version>‑<min python>‑<max python>‑<arch>.whl`

Comment: cp means cython? And what does arch mean here

Comment: Correct, as opposed to other interpreters like PyPy, IronPython.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of all abbreviations in wheel filename notation on Christoph Gohlke's website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924423/what-is-the-meaning-of-all-abbreviations-in-wheel-filename-notation-on-christoph)

Comment: cp39 means cpython 39. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023557/what-does-version-name-cp27-or-cp35-mean-in-python